# Getting attribute error when trying to access the nested serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting following error while using the PostSerializer:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
>   `full_name` on serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field might
>   be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `long`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'long' object has no attribute
>   'full_name'.

Serializers are as follows:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'message', 'rating', 'create_date', 'close_date',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('id', 'username', 'full_name',)
```

View:

```
class PostMixin(object):
    model = Post
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        PostAuthorCanEditPermission
    ]
    queryset = model.objects.all()

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        """Force author to the current user on save"""
        obj.author = self.request.user
        return super(PostMixin, self).pre_save(obj)


class PostList(PostMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    pass
```

User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='U')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field  full_name on serializer UserSerializer.

The model `User` in Django has no such field called `full_name`.
There is though a method `get_full_name()` that does what you want.

### Solution

So try using it through a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('id', 'username') # no full_name here

   full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_full_name')
```

This will add a field called `full_name` to your serialized object, with the value pulled from `User.get_full_name()`

### Check you are using your custom model and not Django's User model

You've customized your own `User` model, but since that models has `full_name`, you shouldn't have gotten that error in the first place, so double check you are not referencing Django's default `User` model first.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User # <--- Make sure this is your app.models.User,
                    # and not Django's User model
       fields = ('id', 'username', 'full_name',) # This is OK on your User model
```

Comment: I have specified my custom user model and updated the same in question. So, I don't think its still required. Still I tried with your solution and I got the following error:

Comment: Error:
long object has no attribute username
Yes, User model is correct as same serializer is working for User API

Comment: Error for username field shows that its a problem for all User fields.

Comment: I have included username in UserSerializer only. I have mentioned the view code as well. I think User serializer is not recieving any kind of user information. If is to so, please help me how to pass it to UserSerializer.

Comment: Also check Django is using your custom model, `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'`

Comment: Getting the error in console: "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: Yes settings is fine.

Comment: I wrote those two lines in PostList view. I don't think its wrong. Also, I am new to Django and DRF also, my few questions may look silly.

Comment: Resolved the issue by making foreign key in post model. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

or just

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```